# how to return decimal value from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which is not returning correct value, for eg. it should return 33.30 but it returns 33.00 which is not desired result.
this is my stored procedure ,i'm using SQL server 2008

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdateStockForSale]
@prodName varchar(40), 
@stqty numeric(9,2),
@batchno varchar(40),
@IsSample varchar(5)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
DECLARE @S_en int;
DECLARE @ttavail numeric(9,0);
DECLARE @ttsold numeric(9,0);
DECLARE @Nr decimal(9,2);
DECLARE @NetRate decimal(9,2)
SET @NetRate=0.0;
While (@stqty > 0) BEGIN

    Select @S_en=S_en,@ttavail=S_P_ttavail, @ttsold=S_P_ttsold,@Nr=NetRate From STOCK WHERE S_P_ttavail>0 AND S_P_name = @prodName  AND S_P_batchno=@batchno And IsSample=@IsSample Order By S_en DESC;

    --If Sale Qty is more than Stock
    IF (@ttavail <= @stqty) BEGIN
        SET @stqty = @stqty - @ttavail;
        SET @ttsold=@ttsold + @ttavail;
        SET @NetRate=@NetRate+(@Nr*@ttavail);
        Print (@NetRate);
        SET @ttavail = 0;
    END
    --If Sale Qty is less than STOCK
    ELSE IF(@stqty < @ttavail) BEGIN
        SET @ttsold = @ttsold + @stqty      
        SET @ttavail = @ttavail - @stqty;   
        SET @NetRate=@NetRate+(@Nr*@stqty);
        Print (@NetRate);
        SET @stqty = 0;
    END 
    Update STOCK Set S_P_ttavail = @ttavail, S_P_ttsold=@ttsold Where S_en=@S_en And IsSample=@IsSample
END
print @NetRate
return @NetRate  
END
```

when I execute it in SSMS I get result

[image]

and message which is showing values i printed ,which shows data fetching n calculations are giving right result [see last printed value] .
[image]

I need this value to save in another table ,so this is C# code

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_UpdateStockForSale ", conn);
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_name"].Value);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stqty", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_otabs"].Value); //total tabs
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batchno ", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_batch_no"].Value);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsSample ", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["IsSample"].Value);

                                var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@NetRate", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                                returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                var result = returnParameter.Value;
```

please help me .thanks.

Comment: make `@return_value` decimal(18,2) for example??

Comment: `RETURN` from a sproc is used to return an **integer error code**. If you want to output a value, you should use an OUTPUT parameter (or more typically, just SELECT it and have the caller read the value).

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: change your SP in function, so you can return a scalar value (as your value). Alternatively, use an output parameter

Comment: @MilenPavlov but i need to do it manually everytime before executing .@returnValue is not declare by me in sp

Comment: @TZHX can u give any example to let me use n know that syntax wise,i've tried using output but it was giving error all the time .

Comment: As @JoeTaras suggested, you can also return a scalar variable (SELECT  @ NetRate instead of Return ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know, It's too late to give answer. As Guffa has already suggested a good solution and it will return correct result as you want.

But, still there is another solution which i would like to share with you that.

use select statement at the end of you stored procedure instead of return statement.

```
      Update STOCK Set S_P_ttavail = @ttavail, S_P_ttsold=@ttsold Where S_en=@S_en And IsSample=@IsSample
    END
  Select @NetRate As NetRate
END
```

and execute your stored procedure by using `ExecuteScalar()` method. How you can avoid unnecessary parameter declaration in you stored procedure.

```
var dNetRate = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

but, still i would like to suggest you to use output parameter if you have no problem in creating another parameter in your stored procedure otherwise you can stick with this solution.

Comment: Thank your for explaining .This is rather easy for me .

Comment: Why isn't this answer getting more upvotes?  I'm afraid it is because of the broken English.  To simply return one scaler value just select what you want returned in your stored procedure and then from C# call var dNetRate = cmd.ExecuteScaler()  (casting from Object to desired type) as shown.  Thanks for the this answer @Shell.  I didn't want to have to add a parameter to my method just to support returning a value through it.  This seems much cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

The return value can only be an integer.

Use an output parameter to get the result from the procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdateStockForSale]
  @prodName varchar(40), 
  @stqty numeric(9,2),
  @batchno varchar(40),
  @IsSample varchar(5),
  @NetRate decimal(9,2) output
AS
...
```

Call it using:

```
declare @Result decimal(9,2)

exec
  [dbo].[sp_UpdateStockForSale]
  @prodName = N'vicks',
  @stqty = 30,
  @batchno = N'v7',
  @IsSample = N'false',
  @NetRate = @Result output
```

In C# you would create an output parameter and add to the parameters before the call:

```
SqlParameter result = new SqlParameter("@NetRate", SqlDbType.Decimal);
result.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command.Parameters.Add(result);
```

After the call (and reading the result set if there is one) you can get the value from the parameter:

```
Decimal netRate = (Decimal)result.Value;
```

Comment: this way do i need to supply any value to @NetRate ?

Comment: @varsha: No, you only have to specify where the output value should go. See: [Returning Data by Using OUTPUT Parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: @Guffa `@nextrate` has been used for sum so need to declare new variable for `output`

Comment: @Justcode: Not at all, just use the parameter instead of creating another variable.

Comment: when i am using @NetRate (same name as in declaration) the it is giving me error in stored procedure

Comment: @varsha: What is the error message? Have you removed the declaration of the variable with the same name?

Comment: no i have not removed that from declaration . error "The variable name '@NetRate' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure."

Comment: @varsha: As the variable exists as a parameter, you don't need to declare it as a variable also. Just use the parameter as the variable.

Answer (score 2):

I had to also specify precision and scale in `SqlParameter` class

```
var output = new SqlParameter("output", SqlDbType.Decimal)
{
     Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
     Precision = 18,
     Scale = 2
};

var sql = "exec dbo.SomeOperation @output OUT";

var result = this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, output);

return (decimal)output.Value;
```

without that, I always got value without decimal points, even though the data type was decimal.